# python 3, exercicio com numeros primos

Tags: python

O menor `m` tal que `n · m + 1` não seja primo.

Exemplo:
Para o primeiro exemplo, `3 · 1 + 1 = 4`, a saída sera `1`.

Para o segundo exemplo, `4 · 1 + 1 = 5`, nós não podemos imprimir `1` porque `5` é primo.

Porem, `m = 2` esta tudo bem, visto que `4 · 2 + 1 = 9`, que não e primo.
Para o terceiro exemplo, `10 · 2 + 1 = 21`, imprimimos `2`.

Escrevi o seguinte código mas esta dando erro:

```
n=int(input())
z=2 
m=1
div=0
x =(n*m+1)
if n>=1 and n<=1000:
           while z<=x-1:
               if x%z==0:
                   div=div+1
               z=z+1
           if div==0:
                m=m+1
                x=n*m+1
           if x==1 or x==2 or x==3:
               m=m+1
               x=n*m+1
           print(m)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que esta seja uma solução válida para o seu problema:

```py
import math


def fast_prime(numero):
    """Função de retorno rapido de números primos"""
    if numero == 1:
        return False

    if numero == 2:
        return True

    if numero == 9:   # Por alguma razão o 9 entra como primo nesse código 
        return False  #  então tive que valida-lo

    if numero % 2 == 0:
        return False

    maiorraiz = int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(numero)))  
    for i in range(3, maiorraiz, 2):
        if numero % i == 0:
            return False

    return True


numero = int(input('Digite um número: '))

multiplicador = 1

equacao = numero * multiplicador + 1

while True:
    if fast_prime(equacao):
        multiplicador += 1
        equacao = numero * multiplicador +1
    else:
        print(f'O valor que satisfaz a equação é {multiplicador}')
        break
```

Espero ter ajudado. Qualquer dúvida, pergunte :)

Comment: Não é necessário converter o retorno de `math.ceil()` para `int()`, pois `ceil()` retorna um inteiro já. E `9` retorna `True` porque o código tentar percorrer um `range(3, 3)`, então ele acaba nem entrando no laço e retornando `True` direto.

Comment: entendi, valeu pela dica!

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente ainda não trouxe a solução, mas reescrevi partes do teu código de forma que ficou mais tranquilo de entender, sem que tenha afetado os resultados.

```
n = int(input('n: '))

z = 2

m = 1

div = 0

x = (n * m + 1)


if n in range(1,1001): # n >= 1 and n <= 1000

           while z <= x - 1:

               if x % z == 0:
                   div = div + 1
               z = z + 1

           if div == 0:
                m = m + 1
                x = n * m + 1

           if  x >= 1 and x <= 3: # x == 1 or x == 2 or x == 3:  
               m = m + 1
               x = n * m + 1

           print(m)
```

Segue um método que verifica se um número é primo que poderá te ajudar na solução.

```
# Recebe um numero inteiro e retorna ele mesmo caso seja um número primo

def verificar_primo(numero):    
    total = 0
    for n in range(1, numero + 1):        
        if numero % n == 0:
            total += 1        
    if total == 2:
        # É primo porque o resto da divisão foi igual a zero duas vezes
        # Em outras palavras, o número foi divisivel por 1 e por ele mesmo
        return numero
```

Comment: Travei na tentativa de te ajudar na matemática porque, por exemplo, não entendi o papel da variável 'z' e porque ela foi inicializada com o valor 2. Seria bom você incluir alguns comentários no seu código explicando o que está fazendo.

Comment: ele utilizou a variável `z` apenas para simbolizar o 2 que no caso é a condição de validação de números primos, o que eu achei um pouco desnecessário criar uma variável para uma constante.

Comment: Ah, entendi, vou tentar resolver... abraço!

Comment: Como pode ver eu já resolvi, mas tudo bem se você também quiser! :)